# how to remove ADD jar statement in the start of beeline

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, beeline, hive-configuration

How can I remove statement that happened when beeline terminal start?
I have AD jar statement by default when I start beeline and I don't have this jar which case error message :

```
ADD JAR /usr/share/hive3-dim-lookup/dimlookup-hive-udf-1.1.....jar;
Error: Error while processing statement{Failed in 10.35.144.186} : //usr/share/hive3-dim-lookup/dimlookup-hive-udf-1.1.....jar does not exist (state=,code=1)
```

When I start beeline, how can I configure it to not start with beeline ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using .hiverc file in users home dir. See [HIVE-5160](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5160)

Check your .hiverc file content:

```
cat ~/.hiverc
```

And remove ADD JAR from it

Comment: i cant find it on my client vm, maybe its in another path?

Comment: i found the init file that start on my beeline it's not that but it gave me the direction , thank you